# Weird screen when Windows 10 wakes up from sleep

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, gpu

I think this happened after my Windows 10 installation was updated to the Creators Update. Whenever I put my laptop to sleep, I get this screen on wake-up:

[image: Weird wake-up image]

My laptop is an MSI PE60-6QE with a GTX960 GPU (it also has Intel's onboard graphics). I have not messed with any settings yet.

To get past it I have to hold the power button to turn the whole thing off and then turn it on again. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install the latest graphic card driver:

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/84889/en